# DAX measure to fill in missing blanks with values

Tags: excel, datatable, powerbi, dax

How do i fill in blank cells with values from adjacent column as per image below.

While keeping max end value throughout rest of the months. Current code giving me half the result.

```
Month   Forecast    Average Actual FTE  Actuals end period
January       0.99      1.25             
February      1.5       0.8              
March         1.19      0.77             
April         1.03      0.75             
May           1.1       1.63             1.63
June          0.99                       1.63
July          1                          1.63
August        3.5                        1.63
September     2.1                        1.63
October       1.6                        1.63
November      1.9                        1.63
December      3.5                        1.64



Actuals end period = 
VAR max_period =
MAXX ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Actual Hours'), 'Actual Hours'[Date])
VAR sum_ = 'Actual Hours'[Actuals]
VAR y =
CALCULATE (
[Actuals],
FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Actual Hours' ), 'Actual Hours'[Date] = max_period )
)RETURN
IF ( ISBLANK ( [Actuals] ), y + sum_ )
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lUZV.png)

Comment: Can you please add your table data here in tabular format instead of image?

Comment: Hi, Added table view of data in original post

Comment: If I understand correct, you wants to repeat last available "Average Actual FTE" to the remaining blank rows. If correct, why it's 1.64 for December?